# Android unable to share file as an attachment

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share a file as an attachment only with the email clients installed on the users device. For this, I am using the below code:

```
String tmp = "file://" + commonMethods.getFromPreferences(Constants.fileNameKey, "string");

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.shareEmailSubject));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.shareEmailText));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(tmp));

((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(emailIntent, 1);
```

With the above code, if I share the file with `GMail` application, it works fine. But if I share them with `Inbox` or `Outlook` application the file does not get added as an attachment.

Is there anything that I am missing or needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO), `ACTION_SENDTO` does not take any extras. There is no requirement for any app to honor any of those extras, let alone all of them.

Beyond that:

- `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` works for `content:` `Uri` values, not `file:` `Uri` values.
- The other apps may not have read access to wherever this file is stored (e.g., external storage).
- `ACTION_SENDTO` with a `mailto:` `Uri` does not limit you to "the email clients installed on the users device". Any app can implement an activity that has a matching `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: Than how can I display just the email clients in the Intent chooser? In some answers I saw that they filter the email clients using `SENDTO` and later share the data using `SEND`. Is that the only possible/best way?

Comment: @PrerakSola: "Than how can I display just the email clients in the Intent chooser?" -- you don't. There is no requirement for email client apps to have some special signature that tells third-party apps that they are email clients. Please let the user share where the user wants.